# Why does sendmail's status keep changing to "dead but subsys locked"?

Tags: linux, centos, services, sendmail

Every day I get the output of `sudo service --status-all` emailed to me using `crond`. The server is a CentOS 6.5 web server which I use to host a few WordPress websites. Occasionally `sendmail` will change from `is running...` to `dead but subsys locked` like in the example below.

```
crond (pid  7768) is running...
httpd (pid  2922) is running...
mysqld (pid  1314) is running...
sendmail dead but subsys locked
openssh-daemon (pid  11173) is running...
```

I normally fix this by restarting the service with this command `sudo service sendmail restart`. The change in status doesn't seem to affect `sendmail` at all as my WordPress sites still send emails fine (which is all I use `sendmail` for).

What is causing this to happen and is it a problem? How do I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out `postfix` and `sendmail` were running at the same time. Something was occasionally causing the `postfix` service to start which then caused the status of `sendmail` to jump to `dead but subsys locked`.

I thought I had checked that `postfix` wasn't running by performing `sudo service --status-all`. Rather confusingly the main process for `postfix` is listed as `master` not `postfix`. Upon scanning the output of `sudo service --status-all` I was expecting to see `postfix (pid xxxx) is running...` and as there was no such line I assumed `postfix` wasn't running!

To fix this I simply performed `sudo service master stop` followed by `sudo service sendmail restart` and all is well again. Now time to track down what's causing `postfix` to start up every now and then...

Comment: You can just use chkconfig postfix off